# WPF - Why SetProperty() not trigger CanExecute when set {Binding BindableObject.Text} in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, command

I use the following NEW BindableViewModel class(Old one I also post at the bottom of this topic) to make a object observable(from MS sample):

```
public abstract class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (object.Equals(storage, value)) return false;

        storage = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I want use this to create a ViewModel in order to bind those TextBox Controls, such as this:

```
public class TextBoxModel : BindableBase
{
    private string _text = string.Empty;
    // I'm going to bind this field to TextBox.Text property
    public string Text { get { return _text; } set { SetProperty(ref _text, value); } }

    private bool _isEnabled = true;
    // I'm going to bind this field to TextBox.IsEnabled property
    public bool IsEnabled { get { return _isEnabled; } set { SetProperty(ref _isEnabled, value); } }
}
```

Then, in my Page ViewModel, I use TextBoxModel to define fields:

```
public class Page1ViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private TextBoxModel _firstName = null;
    public TextBoxModel FirstName { get { return _firstName; } set { 
        if (SetProperty(ref _firstName, value))
            {
                SubmitCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            } } }

    private TextBoxModel _surname = null;
    public TextBoxModel Surname { get { return _surname; } set { 
        if (SetProperty(ref _surname, value))
            {
                SubmitCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            } } }

    private DelegateCommand _submitCommand = null;
    public DelegateCommand SubmitCommand { get { return _submitCommand??(_submitCommand=new DelegateCommand(SubmitExecute, SubmitCanExecute)); } }
    private void SubmitExecute()
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"{FirstName.Text} {Surname.Text}");
    }
    private bool SubmitCanExecute()
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName.Text))
            return false;
        else if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Surname.Text))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

In my XAML View, I set textbox binding as usual:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName.Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsEnabled="{Binding FirstName.IsEnabled}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Surname.Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsEnabled="{Binding Surname.IsEnabled}"/>
<Button Content="Submit" Command{Binding SubmitCommand} />
```

When I run this, I've found text changing is not work. It didn't trigger if(SetProperty(ref _firstName, value)) or if(SetProperty(ref _surname, value)) in the setter. If I don't combine the properties in a TextBoxModel, everything works fine. If I use OLD ViewModelBase, TextBoxModel worked fine, too.

So I think I must missed something when using the NEW BindableBase class? Looking for your help, thanks!

OLD ViewModelBase:

```
[Obsolete("Please use BindableBase。")]
public abstract class ObservableModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public static string GetPropertyName<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T>> e)
    {
        var member = (System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression)e.Body;
        return member.Member.Name;
    }

    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged<T>
        (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged(GetPropertyName(propertyExpression));
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler temp = PropertyChanged;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this could work. You're not setting `FirstName` or `Surname` when the text changes (or, in fact, at all!), so `SetProperty` won't be called.  You need to observe the property changes *within* `TextBoxModel`.

Comment: @CharlesMager what do you mean? I do changed the Text property of FirstName object, but it didn't trigger if(SetProperty(ref _firstName, value)). But, it triggered Text property inside of FirstName object. Why didn't trigger if(SetProperty(ref _firstName, value)) even Text property inside of it triggered?

Comment: Your binding is to the `Text` property, which is a `string`.  Trying to set that value will not magically new up a `TextBoxModel` and set `FirstName` as well.  It will just silently fail because `FirstName` is `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binding will never set `FirstName` or `LastName`, and nothing else you've shown does either.  These will both be `null`.  A binding to `Text` will only set that value, it won't create a new `TextBoxModel` and set that.

If you want this to work while organised this way, you'll need to do something like this:

```
public class Page1ViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private readonly TextBoxModel _firstName = new TextBoxModel();

    public Page1ViewModel()
    {
        _firstName.PropertyChanged += 
            (sender, args) => SubmitCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    public TextBoxModel FirstName 
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @CharlesMager, your code worked, thank you very much. Before I accept your answer, I want to understand something: "_firstName.PropertyChanged += 
            (sender, args) => SubmitCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();" this means when _firstName object changed, than call SubmitCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(), it's ok I understand. But, I did add the same code in setter, also means when _firstName object changed, than call SubmitCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(). why mine not work? (I changed the code to _firstName = new TextBoxModel(); to avoid it null at the start)

Comment: @OhMyDog It means when a `_firstName` *property* changes it will call that method.  Putting in the setter means it will only be called when the object is *replaced*. It will never be replaced (you can see there's no issue caused by removing the setter entirely).

Answer (score 1):

What you trying to do makes sense, but *how* you are doing it is needlessly complicated. You have a `TextBoxModel` which is trying to mimic a *real* `TextBox` which you simply don't need to do, I think your approach is all wrong.

Firstly, the Model represents **data**, not UI. Instead of creating a `TextBoxModel` that represents a `TextBox`, you should instead create a model that represents your data structure, such as a `PersonModel`, or a `UserModel`. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

*Note: You could put `INotifyPropertyChanged` stuff in the Model, but that isn't really a UI concern, it's just data. The best place for the property changed implementation is in the View Model, which I'll explain further down.*

Ok, now the data layer is sorted, you simply need to **expose** this model to the View via the View Model. Firstly, here is a simple property changed base that I will use for this example:

```
public abstract class PropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyOfPropertyChange([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Expose the model properties like this:

```
public class PersonViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private PersonModel _Person;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _Person.FirstName; }
        set
        {
            _Person.FirstName = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _Person.LastName; }
        set
        {
            _Person.LastName = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }

    //TODO: Your command goes here

    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        //TODO: Get your model from somewhere.
        _Person = new PersonModel();
    }
}
```

Now you can simply bind your `TextBox` to the `FirstName` or `LastName` view model property:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName}" ... />
```

It is really as simple as that. You **do not** need to recreate a `TextBox` in your data layer, in fact all UI concerns should be completely separate from the model layer.

Using this method, you also do not need to worry about raising the `CanExecuteChanged` method because it's already handled by `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Remember, **UI is UI, Data is Data**.

Comment: hi @MikeEason thank you for your answer but it didn't solve my problem(I think). I have a form contains about 80 fields need to deploy on UI, every field required IsEnabled & IsFocused properties that I need to control them in ViewModel, with Value property itself, that at least 80x3 = 240 properties in my ViewModel. So I decide to combine these properties by same Control for a easy coding, that all.